# Jquery knob animate

Tags: jquery-knob

I am having trouble animating jquery knob.
As you can see in my example only the last one animates.

```
<input class="knob nummer1 animated" value="0" rel="64">
       <input class="knob nummer2 animated" value="0" rel="77">
       <input class="knob nummer3 animated" value="0" rel="99">
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/johansrk/cvQED/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

local `$this` object  was not getting set for every new instance of knob,instead same `this` object was referenced each time.

so what you need to do is create a new local reference of `this` object for every knob instance.

`var $this = $(this);`

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/cvQED/939/)

**JS CODE:**

```
     $('.knob').each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       var myVal = $this.attr("rel");
       $this.knob({
       });
       $({
          value: 0
       }).animate({
          value: myVal
       }, {
          duration: 2000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function() {
             $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
          }
       });
   });
```

Comment: thanks. Quite close, but I want whole numbers in the animation

Comment: @Johansrk: i didnt get you ? wht do you mean by whole numbers in animation mean ?

Comment: during the animation, the numbers are not whole. It seems like "ceil", does not work

Comment: @Johansrk: more than you this bugged me alot bro, you know what was the mistake , ` $this = $(this);` **$this** here was not getting updated so when i changed it like this ` var $this = $(this);` it worked.can u believe this was the error.